# adding numbers returned from function in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following basic code in powershell where I'm calculating the value of x

```
function add3([int]$num) { 
    return ($num + 3); 
}

[String]$argA = "AB";
[int]$x = (add3($argA.Length) + 2);

Write-Host($x)
```

Running this in ISE I'm getting the value 5 instead of 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerShell, you call functions by listing the arguments separated by spaces, not commas, and parentheses are not used. This is a common source of confusion. Your expression:

```
[int]$x = (add3($argA.Length) + 2);
```

Is a call to the function `add3` with *three* arguments: `($argA.Length)` and the strings `+` and `2`. Since your function has only one argument, the result is `2 + 3 = 5` and the other two are discarded (calling a function with extraneous parameters is not an error in PowerShell). You can verify this is what's happening by changing your function:

```
function add3([int]$num, $y, $z) { 
    Write-Host $y;
    Write-Host $z;
    return ($num + 3); 
}
```

The solution is to parenthesize the expression properly:

```
$x = (add3 $argA.Length) + 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the correct output.

Try to use this approach instead:

```
[int]$x = (add3($argA.Length)) + 2
```

Comment: Can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

```
function add3($num) { 
    return ($num + 3); 
}

[String]$argA = "AB";
$x = (add3($argA.Length)) +2

Write-Host($x)
```